# c# autocad sideload database binding xrefs

Tags: c#, autocad

i am trying to bind xrefs in a sideload drawing database. the program is halting at this line ' if(!xNode.Database.Filename.Equals(NewDb.Filename))'. i am also receiving this error 'System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.at XBind.RecursiveFileProcessor.ProcessFile(String path).' i've done some reaserch and found VB.NET code to attach a xref and tried to extrapolate that with no success. i'd appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction on this.

```
                using (Database NewDb = new Database(false, true))
            {
                NewDb.ReadDwgFile(path, FileOpenMode.OpenForReadAndWriteNoShare, true, "");
                NewDb.CloseInput(true);
                using (Transaction tr = NewDb.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
                {
                    ObjectIdCollection xrefCollection = new ObjectIdCollection();
                    XrefGraph xg = NewDb.GetHostDwgXrefGraph(false);
                    int numOfNodes = xg.NumNodes;
                    for (int cnt = 0; cnt < xg.NumNodes; cnt++)
                    {
                        XrefGraphNode xNode = xg.GetXrefNode(cnt) as XrefGraphNode;
                        if (!xNode.Database.Filename.Equals(NewDb.Filename))
                        {
                            if (xNode.XrefStatus == XrefStatus.Resolved)
                            {
                                xrefCollection.Add(xNode.BlockTableRecordId);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (xrefCollection.Count != 0)
                    {
                        NewDb.BindXrefs(xrefCollection, true);
                    }
                    tr.Commit();
                }
                NewDb.SaveAs(path, DwgVersion.Current);
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this will work in-memory.  Winslow North missing the following line of code after the CloseInput()...

```
NewDb.ResolveXrefs(true, false);
```

But also, you do not need the Transaction for this.  It's not necessary.  I created my own sample and tested it.  It works.  If you need me to post that, let me know.  The problem was that the xNode had a null database due to the fact that the Xref was not resolved.  You have to do that manually with the line above.

Answer (score 0):

Don't believe this will work for in-memory database, you may try [this approach](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2015/01/modifying-the-contents-of-an-autocad-xref-using-net.html), see a pice of it below:

```
[CommandMethod("CHX")]
public void ChangeXref()
{
  var doc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
  if (doc == null) return;

  var ed = doc.Editor;
  var db = doc.Database;

  // Get the database associated with each xref in the
  // drawing and change all of its circles to be dashed

  using (var tr = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
  {
    var bt = (BlockTable)tr.GetObject(db.BlockTableId, OpenMode.ForRead);
    var ms = (BlockTableRecord)tr.GetObject(bt[BlockTableRecord.ModelSpace], OpenMode.ForRead);

    // Loop through the contents of the modelspace
    foreach (var id in ms)
    {
      // We only care about BlockReferences
      var br = tr.GetObject(id, OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockReference;
      if (br != null)
      {
        // Check whether the associated BlockTableRecord is
        // an external reference
        var bd = (BlockTableRecord)tr.GetObject(br.BlockTableRecord, OpenMode.ForRead);
        if (bd.IsFromExternalReference)
        {
          // If so, get its Database and call the function
          // to change the linetype of its Circles

          var xdb = bd.GetXrefDatabase(false);
          if (xdb != null)
          {

            using (var xf = XrefFileLock.LockFile(xdb.XrefBlockId))
            {
              // Make sure the original symbols are loaded
              xdb.RestoreOriginalXrefSymbols();

              xdb.RestoreForwardingXrefSymbols();
            }

          }
        }
      }
    }
    tr.Commit();
  }
}
```